# SUM() different nodes of an XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, sum, bi-publisher

I have an XML like below in BI Publisher-

```
<ROW1>
  <TOTAL_RETAIL>10.95</TOTAL_RETAIL>
  <TOTAL_TAX> 1.8</TOTAL_TAX>
  <TOTAL_SHIPPING>7.95</TOTAL_SHIPPING>
</ROW1>
```

`<ROW1>` does not repeat. Now as I understand to do a `SUM` of a node I can use XPath function `sum()` like `<?sum(.//TOTAL_RETAIL)?>`. This will sum the values of the node `TOTAL_RETAIL` only, I want the sum of `TOTAL_RETAIL`, `TOTAL_TAX`, and `TOTAL_SHIPPING`. Is there a way I can write the `sum` function to achieve this.

Note- It cannot be handled programmatically i.e. using variables etc. since its inside a Report template and has to be defined as `<?sum(...)?>` this values will be mapped to a specific cell in an excel report template.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
<?sum(.//TOTAL_RETAIL | .//TOTAL_TAX | .//TOTAL_SHIPPING)?>
```

`|` is the union operator, so the argument you're passing to `sum()` is the union of the three sub-expressions.

Comment: I have a small problem though. When it adds it shows `20.7" rowmark="4` in the cell in the excell report. The cells are formatted as `currency` other `sum` done in the same way but on a single column i.e. `sum(.//RETAIL)` work fine.

Comment: @Annjawn: That sounds like something specific to BI Publisher, about which I know nothing. Maybe it's a bug in BIP. You could try publishing the report in a different format, and see if the result helps to illuminate why the Excel report is acting the way it is.

Comment: @Annjawn: I was assuming, based on your tagging, that the `<?sum(...)?>` is using the XPath 2.0 `sum()` function. But a quick search for documentation didn't yield any precise semantics of `<?sum(...)?>`.

Comment: It should be using that by default, since `sum()` is an XPath function. `sum()` on a single column works fine but the `union` causes some additional garbage content.

Comment: I figured out out it to be some weird issue with Excel and resolved it. thanks

Comment: @AnjanBiswas I am also having same issue , can you please tell me how you resolved it.

Answer (score 4):

```
sum(.//TOTAL_RETAIL | .//TOTAL_TAX | .//TOTAL_SHIPPING)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also try splitting the sum on each node, it works like this:

```
<?sum(.//TOTAL_RETAIL) + sum(.//TOTAL_TAX) + sum(.//TOTAL_SHIPPING)?>
```

And in case you have NULL values or empty nodes, use this filter to make sure that the sum function will always work: `sum(.//TOTAL_RETAIL[.!='']) + ...etc`